# How to change order of Leaflet layers from different types?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using Leaflet and with different types of layers. I use `TileLayer`, `Callout`, and some markers that I grouped into Leaflet `LeatureGroup`. `Callout` are from extension [leaflet-dvf](https://github.com/humangeo/leaflet-dvf) and extend Leaflet `LayerGroup`, markers come from leaflet-dvf as well and extend Leaflet `Path`.

I need to order the layers, but I can only order them between layers from the same class. I can order `TileLayer` between them, `Callout` between them and all markers between them.
`Callout` are always showing first, then `TileLayer` and finally markers.

I already tried to :

- use the `Layer.bringToBack()` and `Layer.bringToFront()` methods but it only works for layers from the same types.
- use `zIndex` with `Layer.setZIndex()` but it doesn't seem to work at all (I admit I don't really understand how `zIndex` works).
- add the Layers to the map in the order I want them, still doesn't work between layers from different types.
- put all layers into different `featureGroup` so maybe they would act the same, but they don't.

Does anyone knows how I could order them, regardless from there types ?

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/

Comment: IvanSanchez thanks for the anwser. After reading your exemple I tried to use panes but from what I understand all TileLayer are in the same pane, as well as markers, and so on... I would like to be able to display a tile layer, then a marker layer, and then another tile layer. Is this possible ? I read the doc but found nothing.

Comment: I just saw we can pass a pane in the options when create a layer. I will try to use this.